# Why gradle exclude pattern in copy task is not working?

Tags: java, gradle, copy

I wantto create a gradle copy task which will copy files from root folder to subfolder, and I don't want to have duplicates in the resulting folder. What am I missing in my code?

I've tried to exclude resulting folder from the `from` clause, but it doesn't work. Also I've tried to move the `exclude` statement out of scope of `from` and just place it

Initial directory structure:

```
FolderA\
-SomeStuff.java
-FolderB\
--FolderC\Main.java
```

What I want to achive:

```
FolderA\
-SomeStuff.java
-FolderB\
--FolderC\Main.java
-MyNewFolder\
--SomeStuff.java
--FolderB\
---FolderC\Main.java
```

I've created following gradle task:

```
task copyToNewFolder(type: Copy) {
   from('FolderA') {
      include '**/*.java'
      exclude '**/MyNewFolder/**'
   }
   into 'FolderA/MyNewFolder'
}
```

At the moment result looks in the following way:

```
FolderA\
-SomeStuff.java
-FolderB\
--FolderC\Main.java
-MyNewFolder\
--MyNewFolder\
---SomeStuff.java
---FolderB\
----FolderC\Main.java
--SomeStuff.java
--FolderB\
---FolderC\Main.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting a question I've got it to work as expected.

Problem was in the place and pattern of the `exclude`

Changed code to

```
task copyToNewFolder(type: Copy) {
   from 'FolderA' 
   include '**/*.java'
   exclude '**/MyNewFolder/**/*'
   into 'FolderA/MyNewFolder'
}
```